# Converting chars from scanner to dec and hex in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode, char, java.util.scanner

I'm relatively new to Java since we just started working with it in college. So far I haven't been having many problems but our latest task won't let me sleep at night: We're supposed to write a simple program that asks the user to enter a Unicode character into the console using a scanner. The program should then encode said character to its decimal und hexadecimal value.
Here is what I came up with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a Unicode character:");

    char c = scan.next().charAt(0);

    scan.close();


    System.out.println((int)c);
    System.out.printf("%h",c);

}
```

Again, I'm still new to Java so I apologize for any beginner mistakes I'm making. My problem is that the encoder seems to work until I reach a character whose decimal value exceeds 255, which would in my case be "ÿ". If I enter any char beyond that I get a dec of 63 and a hex of 3f
[https://imgur.com/a/HwOPIDl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juPyO.png)

I'm happy about all the help I can get!

Comment: I think your program is ok. The problem might come from your console which might be using an 8 bit encoding

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to print it out, you can use System.out.printf(). This worked for me:

```
System.out.printf("%#08x %d", (int)c, (int)c);
```

In `%#08x`:

`#` automatically slaps on a '0x' prefix

`08` means 8 characters wide, with leading zeros if necessary

`x` is for hexadecimal value

example：

```
你
0x004f60 20320
```

Comment: Thank you! I’ll try this out tomorrow and let you know if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something else with numbers, you can convert it to appropriate data type and then print.

```
    int int_val = (int)c;
    String hex_val = Integer.toHexString(int_val);
}
```